# Socket.io getting disconnected unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

```
<body>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="">
  <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button onclick="message()">Send</button>
</form>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
     var socket = io();

   var message = function(){
       var msg = document.getElementById("m").value;
       if(msg !== ""){
        alert(msg);
       socket.emit('chat message',msg);
       }
       document.getElementById("m").value="";
   }

   socket.on('display',function(value){
       console.log(value);
       document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += "<li>"+value+"</li>";
   })

</script>
```

This is my index.html page to design a group chat using socket.io

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('chat message',function(msg){
        console.log('message: '+msg);
        io.emit('display',msg);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
       console.log('user disconnected')
    })
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("listening on 3000");
});
```

This is my index.js file. The user is getting disconnected each time a message is sent. Any suggestions why this happened

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it throws any error????

Comment: No errors. The user is disconnected on every message sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `message(event)` to your form:

```
<form action="">
  <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button onclick="message(event)">Send</button>
</form>
```

and change your message function to:

```
var message = function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); 
   var msg = document.getElementById("m").value;
   if(msg !== ""){
      alert(msg);
      socket.emit('chat message',msg);
   }
   document.getElementById("m").value="";
}
```

The default html method when you submit a form is GET. When express receives GET it resends `index.html` to the browser and the page refreshes. We can change it with `event.preventDefault()`. It should work now.

Comment: working perfectly with JS. But when using angular, the same problem I had

Comment: You can ask a new question and show us your angular code

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do:

```
io.emit
```

You should do:

```
socket.emit
```